# I'm not able to access my external hard drive even though I have the same security options as my HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I cloned my HDD to my external hard drive using MiniTool Partition Wizard and now I'm not able to access it. Only from Command Prompt with admin rights.

I have opened the security settings of my EHD and my HDD and they are exactly the same.

I have tried the following:

- Using `chkdsk`, didn't change anything.
- Disk Management, all options are grayed out.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the device.
- Trying to
  access it from another computer, it didn't mount automatically and had trouble doing so.

I did try the `takeown` command, but saw that it goes through all individual files and canceled it. Note that I cloned my HDD with 1 TB of files, and like I said before the security settings are the same.

Any idea what else I can try?

Edit: Upon request from Ramhound I tried to takeown a single file.

```
G:\Images\Avatars>takeown /F mario.png
ERROR: File ownership cannot be applied on insecure file systems;
       there is no support for ACLs.
```

This is weird because using takeown on the whole drive seemed to work, but maybe that was with different arguments?

Screenshots of the ACL information:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you take ownership of a single file, with `takeown` and provide the output of the command with an edit to your question.  Take a screenshot of that same file which indicates the ownership of the file, and a second screenshot of the ACL information for the file.

Comment: @Ramhound Done.I hope this is what you meant with ACL information?

Comment: The Users group only has read and execute permissions, which is why you're having trouble. The only way to fix this, is to reset the permissions, let it go through all files and solve the issue for you. That process will take a while though. Alternatively, format the drive then copy the files back, but that will be even slower.

Comment: You need to add **Everyone** to the ACL

Comment: My D:/ drive, the one that I cloned, has the exact same settings though. Why is it that it acts differently? I should also mention that since I still have the original data I'm fine with formatting the drive and retrying if that's somehow faster.

Comment: Did you clone a data disk or a system disk? If it is a system disk, just boot from the cloned disk and try accessing files. But if it is a data disk, you can try copying a partition instead of the whole HDD.

Comment: Yes, my problem was indeed that I cloned the disk instead of the partition. Thanks.